# Should I commit serverless framework .build folder

Tags: git, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am creating lambda function with serverless framework with `typescript-http-api` template. However, I noticed that `.gitignore` file doesn't contain line to exclude `.build` folder.

`.build` folder contains node_modules and obvioulsy large. Should I manually add it to `.gitignore` or there are some caveats that I don't know?

Comment: `node_modules` should not be in your git store! In my opinion, if the `.build` can be made by other things, then you should put it in your `.gitignore`.  Is it used for lock packages' version? Or just some files for cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, build folder should be included in .gitignore, because when the developer pulls the changes, after the compilation he will get the build folder back if the tsconfig.json file is well written and i don't think that it's a good idea to have node_modules inside the build folder

Comment: Thanks! btw `node_modules` appeares automatically in .build I haven't moved it. But I guess it's apparent that it should appear there, because the nature serverless little bit differes from traditional apps.